# How to solve $ 2x-3-2x^{ -1/2 }= 0 $ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

#### Equation to solve

$$
2x-3-2x^{ -(1/2) }= 0
$$

The answer should be $2.1777$. However I'm not too sure how the steps in between are constructed. Anyone can guide me how do I solve x for this equation?

#### Progress

One way that I have tried solving this is

$$
2x-3-2x^{ -(1/2) }= 0
$$
$$
2x-2x^{ -(1/2) }= 3
$$
$$
2(x-x^{ -(1/2) })= 3
$$
$$
x-x^{ -(1/2) }= \dfrac32
$$

Not very sure how do I proceed on from here and whether it is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is not a quadratic equation. If we let $x^{1/2} = u$, we then get that
$$2u^2 - 3 - \dfrac2u = 0 \implies u^3 - \dfrac32u - 1 = 0$$
This is a depressed cubic and solving such depressed cubic can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic). The solution is given as follows:

Let $\alpha = \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{108-54 \sqrt2}}6$, $\beta = \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt2}}{2^{2/3}}$ and $\omega = \dfrac{1+i \sqrt3}2$; then the three solutions are
$$\alpha + \beta; -\alpha \omega - \beta \bar{\omega}; -\alpha \bar{\omega} - \beta \omega$$ Of the three the only real solution is $\alpha + \beta$. Since, $x^{1/2} = u$, the only real solution for the initial equation is $(\alpha + \beta)^2$, which evaluates to $2.177650698804059954962643867932125475959166$ approximately.

Comment: Hi. thank you for your response. that looks pretty confusing....?

Answer (score 1):

$$2x-3-\frac2{\sqrt x}=0\implies(2x-3)^2=\left(\frac2{\sqrt x}\right)^2\implies$$

$$4x^2-12x+9=\frac4x\implies 4x^3-12x^2+9x-4=0$$

I don't think the above has a simple/elementary solution. Are you sure you wrote the correct equation?

Comment: hi, thank you for your entry. yes I'm sure I have written the correct equation down. The answer should be 2.1777. However I'm not sure about the specific steps in between.

Comment: What course is this exercise from? Perhaps you must apply Newton's method to find an approximation orsomething like that?

Comment: Well, there is Cardano's method for solving cubic equations.

Comment: @ТимофейЛомоносов, believe me: Cardano's Method is waaaaaay non-elementary for most students nowadays. In fact, I've never known anyone who studied that in high school or even undergraduate school *as part of the study program*. I, for one, got into that when I was in graduate school and only because I wanted to. Most students, I think, will consider Newton-Rapson or something like that more elementary.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose, just for grins, that the equation is this slight variation:

$$2x^{1/2} -3 -2x^{-1/2}=0$$

Then multiplying through by $x^{1/2}$ yields $2x -3x^{1/2} -2 = 0$

$$ \cdots = (2x^{1/2} +1)(x^{1/2} -2) = 0$$

Comment: hi. thank you chaz for the response. but I need my question to be solved the way it is. any idea how can that be done?

Comment: Why do you call this a quadratic equation? Where did you get that idea?

Comment: hi. sorry. was not too sure of the term. my bad.

Comment: No worries. It just had a few of us scratching our heads! The resulting cubic is solved as in user's answer